# Pyspark JDBC Hana database dataframe.show error

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, hana

I able to connect to Hana database in spark by using python JDBC dataframe  and able to get dataframe.printSchema() output but if i try to do action like dataframe.show() throwing error like connection is not serializable how do we make connection serializable in pyspark 
below is the code used

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="hdfspush")

sqlctx = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlctx.read.format('jdbc').options(driver='com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver',url=urlname,dbtable='abcd').load()

df.printSchema()

df.show()
```

below is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/testhana4.py", line 15, in <module>
    df.show()
  File "C:\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 258, in show
  File "C:\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "C:\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sap.db.jdbc.topology.Host
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: com.sap.db.jdbc.topology.Host, value: saphdbdev03.isus.emc.com:30415)
        - writeObject data (class: java.util.ArrayList)
        - object (class java.util.ArrayList, [saphdbdev03:30415])
        - writeObject data (class: java.util.Hashtable)
        - object (class java.util.Properties, {dburl=jdbc:sap://saphdbdev03:30415, user=SAPSR3, password=*****, url=jdbc:sap://saphdbdev03.isus.emc.com:30415?user=SAPSR3&password=******,
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anonfun$getConnector$1, name: properties$1, type: class java.util.Properties)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anonfun$getConnector$1, <function0>)
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRDD, name: org$apache$spark$sql$jdbc$JDBCRDD$$getConnection, type: interface scala.Function0)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRDD, JDBCRDD[0] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.NarrowDependency, name: _rdd, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency, org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@2e079958)
        - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
        - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@2e079958))
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[1] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
        - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
        - object (class scala.Tuple2, (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2,<function2>))
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1264)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:878)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:815)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1426)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)

15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/api,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump/json,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/json,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment/json,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd/json,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/json,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool/json,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/json,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
15/12/11 14:21:34 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
15/12/11 14:21:35 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.30.117.16:4040
15/12/11 14:21:35 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
```

Comment: can you share the exact error message? Just a quick check, have you included the `ojdbc.jar` as well?

Comment: I included ngdbc.jar while running able to connect to database only problem when action performed on dataframe as you know dataframe is lazy exact database action would be performed when we call any operation added full error log as well above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is resolved by writing new scala programs to handle serialization in connection properties

Comment: How did you resolved it. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: could you be bit more specific ? what exactly needs to be done?